# Run python file in blender from command line

Tags: python, scripting

I have the following structure:

[image]

The repo folder is located over `~/Desktop/Github/` and when I run from the command line `blender --background --python ./Desktop/Github/repo_folder/main.py` I get the following error:

[image]

I want to import all the classes/functions in `utils.py to main.py` to do that I tried the following things:

1) `from scripts.utils import *` got an error that scripts module wasn't recognized.

2) moved main under scripts and edited the line `from .utils import *`

3) tried to create `__init__.py` file under scripts

I use python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 when trying (1) no errors marks shown over the IDE (Pycharm)
Blender version - 2.8 installed using snap (if that helps)

Thank you for helping!

Comment: In python the dots refer to submodules, not folders. Check the __init__.py if it says anything about the utils. 
Also are you sure that you need the utils? If that's an addon there's a good chance all you need is accessible from the main.

Comment: it is not an add on ant the init.py file is empty file

Answer (score 1):

An example that should work with Blender 2.80:
The directory:

```
folder
  | -> main.py
  | -> scripts
         -> __init__.py
         -> hello.py
```

`scripts/__init__.py`:

```
from scripts.hello import *
```

`scripts/hello.py`:

```
def hello():
    print('Hi')
```

`main.py`

```
import bpy
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.path.append('')
    import scripts
    scripts.hello()
```

And you launch it with: `blender -b -P main.py`.

---

Adding Avivsham's answer below. The script directory must be in path. Lazy dynamic loading (put at the beginning of your file):

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
scriptDir = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
if scriptDir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, str(scriptDir))
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Found the solution! since using third party (Blender) ``` import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/aviv/Desktop/Github/VideoReasoning")``` is needed to set the environmental variables

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! since using third party (Blender)

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <path_to_repo>)
```

is needed to set the environmental variables